# Fzf script to cd into directr with spaces

Tags: bash, fzf

Hi i was trying to make a script with **fzf** to **cd** into a dir  by searching name of a file in that directory

```bash
fcd(){
    cd $(find | fzf ) 
}
```

but it will throw error when filename contains *space*, as it will split it into 2.

---

EDIT:
Thanks

> cd "$(...)", not cd $(...); the >quotes are mandatory. –
> Charles Duffy

so Can anyone help with such a script to cd into directories with file names using fzf?

---

#### Actual question before edit V

after so much searching and modifying, i ended up with this

```bash
cd $(fzf| awk '{print "\047"$0"\047"}'|xargs dirname | awk '{print "\047"$0"\047"}')
```

take file tree

```
a
└── b
    └── c d
        ├── e.txt
        └── f g.txt
```

if we change cd with echo in above script and search for 'f g.txt', it will correctly print out 'a/b/c d' and if we type cd 'a/b/c d', it is going to that dir. but when combine both and run like above script, is giving

```
bash: cd: too many arguments
```

whereever i search, i get solution as `cd $(find . -d |fzf)` which is not i needed, i wanted to search a filename and go to it's parent directory.

Thanks in advanced :)

Comment: `cd "$(...)"`, not `cd $(...)`; the quotes are mandatory.

Comment: And no, adding literal quotes to your data cannot and will not substitute for missing syntactic quotes, so the `awk`ery makes no sense.

Comment: To be a little more explicit about how to apply the comment above: `fcd() { cd "$(find | fzf)"; }`

Comment: Or, to deal with moving to the parent directory after having a file identified: `fcd() { local target; target="$(find . -type f -print | fzf)" || return; cd "${target%/*}"; }`

Comment: Thanks, this was exactly what i was looking for 
can you post as an answer, so you will get reputation

Comment: No, a closed question cannot be answered. Anyhow, it's just reiterating what the two duplicates teach (one showing why/when it's necessary to add quotes, the other showing how to get the directory containing a file).